ORACLE SYS_REFCURSOR
why is sys_refcursor after rollback closed? there are no notes in the documentation that the rollback should also close the cursor with the selected data. But in my case YES.

-- open cursor to remember data modificated by old process

PROCEDURE p_get_employ_data(
    in_account_prefix IN ucet_jadro.predcislie%TYPE,
    in_account_number IN ucet_jadro.cislo_uctu%TYPE,
    in_out_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  ) IS
  BEGIN
    OPEN in_out_cursor FOR
      SELECT 
          status_id status,
          balance balance,
          dispo_balance dispo_balance
        FROM employ j
        WHERE j.acc_pfx = in_account_prefix
          AND j.acc_num = in_account_number;
    -- Select get rowcount = 1 into cursor
  END p_get_employ_data;

    l_expected_account SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT specimen_savepoint;
    p_set_employ_data_old_process(...);
    p_get_employ_data(
      in_account_prefix => g_account_prefix,
      in_account_number => g_account_number,
      in_out_cursor => l_expected_account
    );
    
    IF l_expected_account%ISOPEN THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('01. l_expected_account is open'); ----->   IS OPEN
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('01. l_expected_account is closed');
    END IF;
    IF l_expected_account%ISOPEN THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('01a. l_expected_account is open');    ----->   IS OPEN
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('01a. l_expected_account is closed');
    END IF;
    --  rollback to prepare the same data by new process
    ROLLBACK TO specimen_savepoint;
    IF l_expected_account%ISOPEN THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('02. l_expected_account is open');
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('02. l_expected_account is closed');   -----   IS NOT OPEN!!!!
    END IF;

    p_set_employ_data_new_process(...);
    --...


Can you turn that into a [mcve]? I can't recreate what you're describing, but I'm having to tweak it a bit to make it run at all, so might be breaking something...

A cursor is associated with the transaction, so COMMIT and ROLLBACK close all opened cursors in the transaction.

I also am not able to reproduce the problem. The rollback to savepoint does not close the cursor. It could be something you are doing in p_set_employ_data_old_process(...); that is changing your behavior.
